# Find local min, max, saddle point of the function $f(x, y) = 3x^3 − 9x + 9xy^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

$f(x, y) = 3x^3 − 9x + 9xy^2$

I've tried taking the partial derivatives and double derivatives of this function to solve for the local minimum, maximum values, and saddle point but haven't made much progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that

$f_{xx}=18x$, $f_{yy}=18x$,  $f_{yx}=18y=f_{xy}$.

On the other hand, we need both partial derivatives to vanish, so $9x^2-9+9y^2=0=18xy$.

This means that either $x=0$ or $y=0$. In the case that $x=0$, we also have that $y= \pm 1$, by just solving. If $y=0$, then $x= \pm 1$.

The situation is, that to determine if these points are local minima/maxima or saddle points, we should check the [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix):

$$\begin{pmatrix}12x &18y\\18y&18x\end{pmatrix}.$$

You can either check its eigenvalues (both positive means local minimum, both negative means global maximum, and mixed means saddle point.)

However, in practice we can just take the determinant:
$216x-324y=108(2x^2-3y^2)$ and plug in values. It's easy to see that $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ are the max/min (the first is the min, the second is the max, you can check this by looking at values close to it) and the other two critical points $(0, \pm 1)$ are saddle points since the determinant is negative and hence the eigenvalues are mixed.